# How to use multiple iOS bundle IDs for one Google Login API?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

We are trying to integrate Google Login all of our iOS apps, each has a unique bundle ID.

I can see the method for creating a new API per app in the IAM console, and I've also visited this link to create the appropriate plist for the iOS app, but I can only seem to attach one Google app to one iOS bundle ID.

Is there any way to generate multiple iOS plists (the `GoogleServices-Info.plist` file) via the Google IAM console, that all use one API key, for each of our iOS apps with unique bundle IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OAuth2 client ID which gets created can only be associated with a single iOS bundle ID. You can view the generated client ID in the Cloud Console for your project ([API Manager -> Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)) and see that it only a single field can be set for the bundle ID.

You must generate a new Client ID for each of your unique iOS apps. You may find this faster to do directly from the Cloud Console (click on 'Create credentials' -> 'OAuth client ID' -> 'iOS', then click on the newly created key and 'Download plist' for each one).

Comment: Does this also apply to app extensions? Because Google Signin is not working in my app extension despite keychain sharing is activated and working.